# mysql select where column a bigger or smaller by 3 then column b

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table with 3 columns, id,num1,num2
I want to select where num1 is bigger then num2+2 or smaller then num2-2
Can this be done in one query?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from   table
where  num1 > num2 + 2
or     num1 < num2 - 2
```